# What is the name of this kind of political regime run by AI?

Tags: election, constitution, political-system, terminology

What is the name of a political regime where an Artificial Intelligence rules all and make decisions?

Comment: It depends on country, IT company-developer is from. If it is a democracy, than surely this is a democratic and tolerant AI. If it is not - surely it is not. I doubt if AI would be uninfluenced by its creators.

Comment: I believe it's called "science fiction".

Comment: Why make it unnecessarily complicated?  It’s a dictatorship.

Comment: Pretty ambiguous in my opinion, what do you call a political regime run by humans / a human?

Comment: @DrCopyPaste For example. Mengsk from Starcraft. He was a dictator. AI can provide a better political structure then human based. I am not strong in politics or economics. I head about that idea in the past, but I recently found it in the book called “Best things money can’t buy”. What do you think about it?

Comment: @Tofesly That just means whoever designed the AI is running the regime.

Comment: @Tofesly then again, there are multiple examples where a government is officially run by only one person, but not all of them are called dictatorships, same could apply to being ruled by an AI (or multiple ones, correcting each other because they were trained using different data, and then, it might not be so different from being ruled by humans after all :D)

Comment: [Technocracyhttps](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technocracy) and [Cyberocracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyberocracy)

Comment: @user253751 no, it is not. If you have "true" AI (tm) that is not true anymore, this would be like saying, if I rule a country that really means my parents rule it, just because they made me...

Comment: @DrCopyPaste It would be true if your parents had conditioned you to do whatever they say when they utter the secret codeword.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste humans have propensity to make decisions based on their interests and benefit. I am talking about AI that will make right decisions to all, not only for  few of nations

Comment: @user253751 exactly, IF one was conditioned that way AND the parents are still alive :)

Comment: @Tofesly in the special case that this ai always makes the "right"(tm) decisions that would come close to being an aristocracy (rule of the "best" - just not with a human monarch but an AI one)

Comment: @DrCopyPaste Ok.I understand now.There is no a new word for this type of government structure. It is an old type of goverment, but with some changes. Technocracy is the best way to explain this idea. The smartest people rule the world when AI helps to plan and make decisions. Thanks for discussion.

Comment: Asimovcracy perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One very recent [paper](https://doi.org/10.1145/3340764.3344438) proposed the term "aicracy". It's too early to tell if this will take off (as a term).

Some users have suggested in the comments that this should be called dictatorship. I think that depends whether the people would accept being ruled by AI or not. There's actually a [recent article](https://qz.com/1576057/could-ai-make-better-policy-than-politicians/) on this (*not* using the term "aicracy" by the way), citing an actual survey.

> The Center for the Governance of Change at Spain’s IE University polled 2,500 adults in the UK, Spain, Germany, France, Ireland, Italy, and the Netherlands in January [2019]. The results reflect an intense anxiety about the changes brought about by advances in tech, with more than half of respondents worried that jobs would be replaced by robots, and 70% saying that unchecked technological innovation could do more harm than good to society. Respondents also expressed concerns about the impact of digital relationships replacing human contact as more people spend time online.
>
> Perhaps most interestingly, a quarter of the respondents said they would prefer AI to guide decisions about governance of their country over politicians. [...]
>
> The study also found that respondents expected governments to reduce the disruption that technology might have on their lives with regulation, limits on automation, and support for people affected by job losses. This “highlights the paradox in which we live,” the authors wrote. “People are disillusioned with governments, yet at the same time ask them to tackle the societal and economic negative effects that emerging technologies might have.”

So yeah, some people would "welcome our machine overlords", but apparently most won't. Of course, it's all theoretical, since we don't have a real general-purpose AI and most of the [stuff written on the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_risk_from_artificial_general_intelligence) seems to ponder whether it will accept us rather than the other way around...

Comment: It’s a good way to call it, but I meant good AI. Now I understand. Check out my latest comment in comment section. It is the answer on my question. You were the first to who answered and seems the only one. So, this point is yours :)